# Separating logic from graphics in animated simulation

Tags: java, animation, graphics, simulation

I need to write a program that acts like an animated simulation of some process. Without going in detail there will be snails (lecturer's idea) moving on checkerboard-like surface where every rectangle (i call it a cell) has (x, y) coordinates.

I have a problem with separating logic of this simulation from graphics. For example:

I have a `Snail` class. It stores snail's coordinates and calculates its behavior. When it determines that snail should move from (x, y) to (a, b) I need to animate that move so I also have to calculate snail's position in pixels and I need to do it repeatedly over some period of time for snail to fluently move, not jump. This wouldn't be a problem if not for the fact that I don't want to do it in the `Snail` class because it's strictly graphic related without any relation to logic.

I can't just make a loop that draws `Snail`s based on their coordinates on checkerboard because it doesn't reflect it's fluent movement, just current position.

My best idea for now is to extend `Snail` by `GraphicSnail` which would additionally calculate and store properties like snail's position in pixels but that doesn't seem separate enough to me.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Use an intermediate interface to make the separation:

```
public interface SnailObserver {
   void update(Snail snail);
}
```

Then make your graphic related class implement this interface. I don't know what library (if any) you are using to render graphics. In case you are using something like JavaFX, the `GraphicSnail` class could also inherit from `ImageView` or something.

```
public class GraphicSnail implements SnailObserver {

    @Overrride
    public void update(Snail snail) {
        // Use snail.getX() and snail.getY() to obtain 
        // position of the snail and perform whatever
        // graphical updates you wish to make
    }      

}
```

Finally, this is what the `Snail` class could look like. Notice the additional field which holds a refference to the `GraphicSnail`, but does so through the `SnailObserver` interface. This is where the separation lies. Note that you could also store a whole list of such observers. In any case, the crucial part is to call the `update()` method on the observer object whenever state of the `Snail` object changes, thus making the observer aware that something has changed. The observer object then examines the current state of the `Snail` object and modifies its own state accordingly.

```
public class Snail {

    private double x;
    private double y;
    private SnailObserver observer;

    public void move() {
        // Move the snail and then notify the observer
        // that the snail has changed like so: 
        observer.update(this);
    }

    public void registerObserver(SnailObserver observer) {
        this.observer = observer;
        observer.update(this); // initial sync
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

}
```

Finally, don't forget to register the observer after you create the `Snail` and `GraphicSnail` objects:

```
Snail snail = new Snail();
GraphicSnail graphicSnail = new GraphicSnail();
snail.registerObserver(graphicSnail);
```

Hope this helps,
stepan

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Stephan's answer, implement [observable properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm) in your model classes for the simulation.  Create separate skin classes that are responsible for the visual representation of the observable model classes.  Assign the skin a reference to the model when you create the skin and, in the skin, add listeners to the listenable properties of the model so that the skin can react to model state changes as appropriate.

For an example of this approach, see the Square and SquareSkin and Board and BoardSkin classes in from this [Tic-Tac-Toe code](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5115901).  Here is an excerpt:

```
class Square {
  enum State { EMPTY, NOUGHT, CROSS }

  private final SquareSkin skin;

  private ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<State> state = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(State.EMPTY);
  public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<State> stateProperty() {
    return state.getReadOnlyProperty();
  }
  public State getState() {
    return state.get();
  }

  private final Game game;

  public Square(Game game) {
    this.game = game;

    skin = new SquareSkin(this);
  }

  public void pressed() {
    if (!game.isGameOver() && state.get() == State.EMPTY) {
      state.set(game.getCurrentPlayer());
      game.boardUpdated();
      game.nextTurn();
    }
  }

  public Node getSkin() {
    return skin;
  }
}

class SquareSkin extends StackPane {
  static final Image noughtImage = new Image(
      "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/double-j-design/origami-colored-pencil/128/green-cd-icon.png"
  );
  static final Image crossImage = new Image(
      "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/double-j-design/origami-colored-pencil/128/blue-cross-icon.png"
  );

  private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

  SquareSkin(final Square square) {
    getStyleClass().add("square");

    imageView.setMouseTransparent(true);

    getChildren().setAll(imageView);
    setPrefSize(crossImage.getHeight() + 20, crossImage.getHeight() + 20);

    setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        square.pressed();
      }
    });

    square.stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Square.State>() {
      @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Square.State> observableValue, Square.State oldState, Square.State state) {
        switch (state) {
          case EMPTY:  imageView.setImage(null);        break;
          case NOUGHT: imageView.setImage(noughtImage); break;
          case CROSS:  imageView.setImage(crossImage);  break;
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The use of model classes and skin classes is how the UI controls for JavaFX are created.  If you review the implementation of the control classes and their skins in the [JavaFX source code base](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9-dev/rt/file/c734b008e3e8/modules/javafx.controls/src/main), you can see how this works.

In general, I think creating controls by extending [Control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html) and using the inbuilt [SkinBase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/SkinBase.html) class, is overkill for most apps.  But, you could evaluate the approach for your needs.  Likely you would be better off using something simpler like the observer to skin approach in the Tic-Tac-Toe code linked before.

Additionally, depending on how far you want to go with this, you can separate [layout definition from code using FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm) and style from code using [CSS stylesheets](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiu08GF0cnYAhVBxoMKHThCD6UQFgg1MAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F8%2Fjavafx%2Fapi%2Fjavafx%2Fscene%2Fdoc-files%2Fcssref.html&usg=AOvVaw3d0J5_RGuh9_S4qnPhB2zA).  I recommend using stylesheets in most cases.  For the case that you describe, the FXML separation may not be necessary.